# getItemIdAtPosition() problem in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am using  the getItemIdAtPosition() to get the Basecoulmns id of the record in Sqlite Database.

the code is below:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(Constants.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, BaseColumns._ID + "="
                        + l.getItemIdAtPosition(position), null, null);
}
```

But its does not retrieves the id correctly. Is this method depends some thing at the time of setting adapter or creation of DB? I have no idea. why it shows the position of the listview. Any Idea?

Edit:

the code for getView mehod :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.brutube_videos, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_text2);
            holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_rate_text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_text2);
            holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_rate_text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.vdo_icon);
        }
        if (!mBusy) {
            try {
                Log.v("getview", "" + (position) + " - " + VAL3[position]);
                holder.icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(new URL(VAL3[position])
                                .openConnection().getInputStream()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            holder.icon.setTag(null);
        } else {
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_video_icon);

            // Non-null tag means the view still needs to load it's data
            holder.icon.setTag(this);
        }
        holder.text1.setText(VAL1[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(VAL2[position]);
        holder.text3.setText(VAL4[position] + " Ratings");

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting your desired value of your list row views as a tag. In your list's viewbinder or adapter use setTag() on your rows view.

Then call (long) v.getTag(); on list item click

*Edit to include sample code for a BaseAdapter*

```
/* In Your BaseAdapter */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout view;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = (RelativeLayout)layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_row, null);
    } else {
        view = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
    }
    long myIdFromDB = // Do your database work

    // Set Tag
    view.setTag(myIdFromDB);

    return view;
}

/* Your listItemClicked method */
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // Get Tag
    long baseColumnId = (long)v.getTag();

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(Constants.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION, BaseColumns._ID + "="
                    + baseColumnId, null, null);
}
```

Comment: ThanX for reply. Can you explain it with some sample code. I can not get you completely.

Comment: Sure, can you explain a bit more about how you are populating your list? Are you populating it from a Cursor? If so, do you use a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: From the looks of your sample code you are already setting the tag of the convertView to a ViewHolder instance. You could add a property to ViewHolder that can hold the id, then when you do listItemClick you would do ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag(); long baseColumnId = vh.getMyId();

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is helpful but you can [check out](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java&q=CursorAdapter&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) how the standard Android CursorAdapter passes the id along and maybe do something similar in your implementation.

More specifically, check out getItemId and hasStableIds.